# In React native useEffect ,using async call i am getting a undefined , How to avoid that undefined in the below case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

These are calls I am using In UseEffect due to the short delay, I am getting undefined in the TAGID, later I am getting data and setting in setState.Now the issue is next I am calling the firebase, there it was storing an undefined document in Firestore database to avoid that undefined or any other approach with firebase calls. How to call the Firestore call in the useEffects or how to avoid that undefined in this case.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resData = await axios(apiURL);
    if (resData.data) {
      setTag(resData.data);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
  const TAGID = "" + tag.id + "";
  const USERID = "" + viewer.id + "";
  const tagsListener = db.doc(TAGID).onSnapshot(function (doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const getData = doc.data();
      setTaginfo(getData);
    } else {
      db.doc(TAGID).set(tagSaveData);
      setTaginfo(tagSaveData);
    }
  });
  return () => tagsListener();
}, []);
```

Comment: 1. you have to `await fetchData()`, however 2. setting state is also async, which means you need `const newTag = await fetchData();`, then use `newTag` in the rest of your code and also call `setTag(newTag);` 3. however for that to work, `fetchData` needs to return a promise that resolves to the loaded data

Comment: If `tag` is state it needs to be in the dependency array otherwise it won’t have a value even after `setTag` is run

Comment: Here's how to 1. fetch data 2. set state based upon it 3. run more code based on that: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-snowflake-mw026?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

fetchData is an async function, you should wait until it finishes, you can do this:

```
fetchData().then(tag=> {
const TAGID = "" + tag.id + "";
const USERID = "" + viewer.id + "";
const tagsListener = db.doc(TAGID).onSnapshot(function (doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const getData = doc.data();
      setTaginfo(getData);
    } else {
      db.doc(TAGID).set(tagSaveData);
      setTaginfo(tagSaveData);
    }
  });
}
)
```

Comment: For that to work, `fetchData` needs to return a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

After returning promise also I am getting undefined in the return

```
useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const resData = await axios(apiURL);
        if (resData.data) {
          setTag(resData.data);
        }
      };
    
      fetchData().then(newTagID =>{
    if(tag){
    tag.id
    return;
    }
    })
      const TAGID = "" + newTagID.id + "";
      const USERID = "" + viewer.id + "";
      const tagsListener = db.doc(TAGID).onSnapshot(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const getData = doc.data();
          setTaginfo(getData);
        } else {
          db.doc(TAGID).set(tagSaveData);
          setTaginfo(tagSaveData);
        }
      });
      return () => tagsListener();
    }, []);
```